# Package algorithm

Tags: indentation, algorithms, bold, pseudocode

I am using `algorithm` package in order to create a pseudocode. But I would like to modify the way it appears some lines.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE{Actividades Programadas}
\STATE Construcción de Soluciones
\STATE Actualización de feromona
\STATE Acciones del demonio
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Procedimiento de ACO}\label{alg:algoritmoRaro}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I would like the text "Actividades Programadas" to appear in bold and with not number. 
Also  Construcción de Soluciones, Actualización de feromona,  Acciones del demonio to be number and indented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I provide `\nonumSTATE` to set a regular `\STATE` without the numbering. Also, `\BEGININDENT`...`\ENDINDENT` is an environment that indents its contents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nonumSTATE}{\item[]}
\newcommand{\BEGININDENT}{\begin{ALC@g}}
\newcommand{\ENDINDENT}{\end{ALC@g}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \nonumSTATE {\bfseries Actividades Programadas}
    \BEGININDENT
      \STATE Construcción de Soluciones
      \STATE Actualización de feromona
      \STATE Acciones del demonio
    \ENDINDENT
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Procedimiento de ACO}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Setting the `\nonumSTATE` to be **bold** automatically is possible (for example, if you write your code to supply the content as an argument - like you did in the original post), but using `\textbf` or `\bfseries` seems sufficient.